# WSO2 Developer Studio Nullpointer exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wso2, esb

I am using WSO2 Developer Studio latest version 3.8.0 on Mac OS High Sierra. Each time when I drag and drop element from the tool pallet into the design workspace, It shows Null pointer exception. Also canvas title is not visible. Here below I attached a screenshot. So much appreciate your help.

[Nullpointer exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbL7q.png)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face similar issue since I install both Oracle JDK 8 and JDK 10. Eclipse take latest JDK 10 version, but application does not support Java 10. To select Java version to use, I added following line into the /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini file. Then it work fine.

`-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

If you are using Java 10 then you can remove it and install Java 8 or you can use both version and update eclipse.ini file to point JDK 8 version.

Hope this will be helpful.